# How to Display Out of Stock Simple Products For Bundle Product Types (Magento 2.2.4)

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, magento2.2.4, out-of-stock

Is there any way to show out of stock simple products which are assigned to a bundle product. Current functionality hides out of stock simple products from the bundle product page.

I know we can display out of stock via the config however is the anywhere in the collection where we can simply show these products. We need the config to stay as is and only have this for bundle products. I want to style them to display out of stock rather than hiding them completely.

Any guidance we be most welcomed thank you.